# Use iteration helpers like .map(), .where(), etc in an async manner?

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, future, dart-async

**Short:** `toList()` executes before `makeMaker` causing the `markers` to have `null` objects.

**Long:** In Firestore, I have `table` and `game` collections and inside of `table`, there is a `game` field(type=reference). With a `StreamBuilder`, I can access `table`s. And I iterate through `table`s and try to fill in their `game` fields with real data by using `get` as seen in below;

```
if (snapshot.hasData) {
            tabledocs = snapshot.data.documents;
            markers = tabledocs
                .map((tabledoc) {
              DocumentReference gameref = tabledoc.data['game'];
              //game field is a reference type field which points to another collection
              gameref.get().then((gdoc) {
                tabledoc.data['game'] = gdoc;
                Marker marker = makeMarker(tabledoc);  //<--------Executes later
                return marker;
              });
            }).toList();                               //<--------Executes first
          }
```

Because `gameref.get().then()` takes time, the `toList()` at the bottom executes before each marker is generated and added in to `markers`.

If there are 3 markers returned from Firestore, our `markers` is an array of 3 `null` `marker`s. I think `makeMarker(..)` did not execute yet most probably.

Is there a way for the `map` method to wait for the `get`s to finish and then initialize `markers` array with non-null values? Or can you show me another way to accomplish what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use

```
await for(var tabledoc of tabledocs) { 

}
```

or if it is not necessary that the items are executed in order (the result will be in the order of the original items though)

```
var markers = await Future.wait(tabledocs
  .map((tabledoc) {
    DocumentReference gameref = tabledoc.data['game'];
          //game field is a reference type field which points to another collection
    var gdoc = await gameref.get();
    tabledoc.data['game'] = gdoc;
    Marker marker = makeMarker(tabledoc);
    return marker;
  });
```

Comment: Very cool. I'd never seen `await for` so would've gone for `Future.wait()`. But the `await for` reads much cleaner to me now that I see it.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer compiler says `Unexpected text: await`. Should I put `async` somewhere in the `streamBuilder`? I already have `import 'dart:async';`

Comment: You shouldn't do such stuff in `StreamBuilder`. Better to do it in `initState` or `didChangeDependencies`, and use `setState(...)` store the result in a field  and initiate rebuild. You might need to move the code to a method that you call from `initState` to be able to use `async`.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer markers are the map pins/markers I am fetching from Firestore. This is the reason I want them to be in `streamBuilder`. Markers not only have `GeoLocations` but `Text` info stored in them which often gets updated. And I want the world map to display these changes instantly. If I do the fetching in `initState` can I still have this functionality. I am stuck really bad Günter:/

Comment: Fetching them from Firestore is probably a good reason to not use `StreamBuilder` otherwise they will be fetched every time the widget is rebuilt.

Comment: I believe my real trouble is the nested document fetching. Since Firestore does not return the whole reference object but just the reference id, I need to make a `Get`. I can't see how I can do this in `initState` since at that time I don't even have the upper level snapshot in my hand.

Comment: Ok I will try to change the code as much as I can according to your guidelines. Will write back soon. Thanks as always

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks for leading me towards the right path